# Cordova Version for Android Kitkat App

Tags: cordova

I want to build a Cordova Application.

Which Cordova Version should i install to build an application for Android Kitkat Version ?

Is it 4.0   or    5.0

Answer (score 2):

You can use latest cordova version, and yo can specify target-platform in your config.xml as so that application built will support all the android versions

```
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />   //android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default.
```